# Javascript 2D Array Loop Stopping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Im writing a program to which I need to retrieve values from multiple input boxes and stash them in a 2D array so that I can $.post them to a php file.

The problem is, the loop seems to stop upon reaching "scoresScores[j][k] = $(this).val;" part. But whenever I comment out that part, it will loop just fine. What seems to be the problem?

UPDATE: It's not just the loop that stops, all the code below scoresScores doesn't get executed.

```
if(flag){

            studIDs = [];
            scoreScores = [[]];
            pScores = [];

            $(".studID"+term).each(function(i){

                studIDs[i] = $(this).text();

                for(var j = 0; j < countTypes; j++){

                    pScores[j] = $("#txtPScoreEdit"+term+"-"+j).val();

                    $(".txtScoreEdit"+term+"-"+j).each(function(k){

                        if(k == i){

                            scoreScores[j][k] = $(this).val();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            when($.post("/res/php/editScores.php",{

            studIDs: studIDs,
            scoreSubjEDP: <?php echo $_GET['EDPCode']?>,
            scoreTerm: term,
            scoreScores: scoreScores,
            pScores: pScores

            })).done(function(){

                location.reload();
            });
        }
```

Comment: oh sorry, it was the auto-tag thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `scoreScores` only has one nested array @ `index === 1`

So when you loop and `j > 0` or `k > 0` it will fail.

You just need to make sure the indexes are valid.

*edit*:

If sparse arrays are OK, the following should work:

```
if(k == i){

    if(!scoreScores[j]) { scoreScores[j] = []; }
    scoreScores[j][k] = $(this).val();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but can you point that out in my code please? I don't quite get it. Thank you